# The use of the word nearly

Tags: modifiers

I would like to compare  the  following two sentences in terms of meaning so as to see how replacing modifiers can cause to change the meaning completely.

> 1. He earned nearly $100.
> 2. He nearly earned $100.

For me, the first sentence has a sense that he earns  an amount  close to $100  or almost $100. However, I could not figure out if the second sentence has a misleading meaning or  it does not just make a sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'nearly' can be read to modify a different element of each sentence.

> He earned nearly $100.

'nearly' modifies the $100 amount. Therefore the sentence can be read as 'he earned an amount slightly less than $100', say, $95.

> He nearly earned $100.

'nearly' modifies **earned** here. Therefore the sentence can be read as 'he had the opportunity to earn $100 but it didn't work out.'

Comment: I see. So I would rephrase the second sentence in this way  : " He was going to earn $100 .(but he could not or did not because he did not get the job). Thanks :)

Comment: btw how to put together correctly  an amount + close + $100 ..is it  " an amount close to $100"  or  " an amount to close $100" ?

Comment: Yes, you could rephrase the second part of the sentence in that way. And to answer your second comment, "an amount close to $100" is the correct usage.